# Create a dataframe out of each group when using the groupBy method

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, aws-glue

Created a data frame out of the following sample data:

```
data = [('James','','Smith','1991-04-01','M',3000),
  ('Michael','Rose','','2000-05-19','M',4000),
  ('Michael','Rose','Rose','1978-09-05','M',4000),
  ('Jen','Mary','Jones','1967-12-01','F',4000),
  ('Jen','Mary','Brown','1980-02-17','F',-1)
]

columns = ["firstname","middlename","lastname","dob","gender","salary"]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data=data, schema = columns)
```

Grouped the data based on `firstname` and `middlename`:

```
grouped = df.groupBy(['firstname', 'middlename']).count()
+---------+----------+-----+
|firstname|middlename|count|
+---------+----------+-----+
|    James|          |    1|
|  Michael|      Rose|    2|
|      Jen|      Mary|    2|
+---------+----------+-----+
```

We get 3 groups with 1, 2, and 2 objects respectively.

How do I create 3 dataframes one for each group?

Expected output:
dataframe 1

```
firstname middlename lastname dob gender salary
James                Smith    ...
```

dataframe 2

```
firstname middlename lastname dob gender salary
Michael   Rose        ...     ...     ...
Michael   Rose        ...     ...     ...
```

dataframe 3

```
firstname middlename lastname dob gender salary
Jen       Mary        ...     ...     ...
Jen       Mary        ...     ...     ...
```

Comment: whats your expected output?

Comment: My expected output is a list of 3 dataframes one for each group that we get using the `groupBy` method

Answer (score 0):

One rather straightforward approach would be to collect all the possible values and then create one dataframe per value by filtering the main one:

```py
# collecting all the distinct values
rows = df.select('firstname', 'middlename').distinct().collect()

# creating one dataframe by value by filtering on the first one
dataframes = [ df.where(
    (df.firstname == r.firstname) & (df.middlename == r.middlename)
) for r in rows ]

# just checking
for small_df in dataframes:
    small_df.show()
```

```
+---------+----------+--------+----------+------+------+
|firstname|middlename|lastname|       dob|gender|salary|
+---------+----------+--------+----------+------+------+
|    James|          |   Smith|1991-04-01|     M|  3000|
+---------+----------+--------+----------+------+------+

+---------+----------+--------+----------+------+------+
|firstname|middlename|lastname|       dob|gender|salary|
+---------+----------+--------+----------+------+------+
|  Michael|      Rose|        |2000-05-19|     M|  4000|
|  Michael|      Rose|    Rose|1978-09-05|     M|  4000|
+---------+----------+--------+----------+------+------+

+---------+----------+--------+----------+------+------+
|firstname|middlename|lastname|       dob|gender|salary|
+---------+----------+--------+----------+------+------+
|      Jen|      Mary|   Jones|1967-12-01|     F|  4000|
|      Jen|      Mary|   Brown|1980-02-17|     F|    -1|
+---------+----------+--------+----------+------+------+
```

Another approach that would avoid reading the main dataframe multiple times would be to write the main dataframe on the disk, partitioned by firstname and middle name and then to read all the resulting dataframes separately.

It could be written like this:

```py
df.write.partitionBy("firstname", "middlename").parquet("my_data")
```

```
tree -d my_data/
my_data/
├── firstname=James
│   └── middlename=__HIVE_DEFAULT_PARTITION__
├── firstname=Jen
│   └── middlename=Mary
└── firstname=Michael
    └── middlename=Rose
```

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

# A function that handles the __HIVE_DEFAULT_PARTITION__ case
def get_key(key):
    if key == '' or key is None:
        return "__HIVE_DEFAULT_PARTITION__"
    return key

# the main logic: a function that reads each dataframe separately
# Note that if we want to have the firstname and middlename columns,
# we need to add them explicitely (the select) We may omit that line
# if you don't need these two columns that would be the same for all
# the dataframe
def gen_small_df(row):
    return (
        spark.read
           .parquet(f"my_data/firstname={get_key(row.firstname)}/middlename={get_key(row.middlename)}")
           .select([F.lit(row.firstname).alias("firstname"), F.lit(row.middlename).alias("middlename")] + df.columns[2:])
    )

# very cheap because df_on_disk is partitioned
rows = df_on_disk.select("firstname", "middlename").distinct().collect()
dataframes = [ gen_small_df(r) for r in rows ]
```

Comment: While this approach works, it is not ideal if the number of `rows` is a large number. Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: How many distinct names do you have? And what do you want to do with all these dataframes? In general, creating multiple dataframes is not a good idea since spark can only handle one dataframe at a time. Therefore I don't think that there is a "good" solution to your question. It could be interesting to take one step back and address the problem differently.

Comment: I added another approach that would not filter the dataframe multiple times but that would use the disk instead. Yet I maintain that it would probably by interesting to rethink the whole approach.